# PHP variable as table name in SQL query

Tags: php, jquery

Can a PHP variable be used as a table name in an SQL query? In my case the PHP variable that goes after FROM should be the value being sent from my JQuery code. I want the SQL query to change based on the value sent from JQuery (different value depending on which option of the select box is chosen).

```
$file_absolute = ---Placeholder for correct file path---;
include_once($file_absolute);
$mysql = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
$verb_value = $_POST['verb_value'];

$mysql->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

$result = $mysql->query("SELECT present_tense FROM $verb_value");
```

Comment: STOP. Don't do this. You're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are just begging to get your server pwn3d.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this, yes. Whether you want it is quite another matter - if you're adding user input to your SQL queries, you've got a huge SQL injection hole.

That said, with table names, you can implement a whitelist, and compare the passed values against that to get a measure of security.

You can't pass table names (or column names) as bound parameters, though - they need to be generated as part of the query.

Comment: Glad you answered this Andrew. I was about to go research binding methods.

Comment: The user is never typing in anything. The value being sent is a value I send based on what option is selected by the user in a select box.

Comment: You're taking in data from `$_POST['verb_value']` - what is there to stop a user from editing the value that's being submitted?

Comment: @andrewsi I'm not sure how the user would edit the value. I'm using the following JQuery code: $('#verb').live('change', function()
   {
      $.post("loadTextBox.php", {verb_value: $(this).val()},
      function(data)
      {
         $("#textbox").html(data.first);
         $("#textbox2").html(data.second);
         $("#textbox3").html(data.third);
         $("#textbox4").html(data.fourth);
         $("#textbox5").html(data.fifth);
         $("#textbox6").html(data.sitxh);
      },"json");
   });

Comment: With tools like firebug, you can see what values are about to be submitted on a page, and edit them before submitting. Also, could I create a form locally that has your PHP page as it's action? Then I can enter whatever I want to.

Comment: @andrewsi Can you suggest another way to do this?

Comment: All you need to do is create an array of tablenames ("user", "company", etc). If the value that's been submitted doesn't match one of those values, you reject it.

Comment: That way, I can try and submit 'company; DELETE FROM user' but the code will ignore it because it's an invalid entry.

Answer (score 0):

A double-quoted string will parse any variables within it, so this will work. A single-quoted string would not.

However, this is generally not considered secure. I'm not sure if you can use a bindParam method to achieve this (I use PDO, not mysqli) as it's not actually a parameter.