# JQuery $.post with data parsing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get textboxes to populate using JQuery based on an array sent from an external PHP file using json_encode(array). The select box option that is selected determines which option value gets sent to the external PHP file. Unfortunately, my textboxes are always empty. I have been trying to debug with Firebug and lint sites, but I can't figure out why there is no population. ***Ignore the security part of this please***

Main index page snippet:

```
function loadDoc()
{
   $('#verb').live('change', function()
   {
      $.post("loadTextBox.php", {verb_value: $(this).val()},
      function(data)
      {
         $("#textbox").html(data.first);
         $("#textbox2").html(data.second);
         $("#textbox3").html(data.third);
         $("#textbox4").html(data.fourth);
         $("#textbox5").html(data.fifth);
         $("#textbox6").html(data.sitxh);
      },"json");
   });
}
```

External PHP file code:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8');

$file_absolute = "---placeholder for correct file path---";
include_once($file_absolute);
$mysql = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
$verb_value = $_POST['verb_value'];

$mysql->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

$result = $mysql->query("SELECT present_tense FROM $verb_value");

$queryResult = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    $queryResult[] = $row->present_tense;
}
$textboxValue = $queryResult[0];
$textboxValue2 = $queryResult[1];
$textboxValue3 = $queryResult[2];
$textboxValue4 = $queryResult[3];
$textboxValue5 = $queryResult[4];
$textboxValue6 = $queryResult[5];
$array = array('first'=>$textboxValue,'second'=>
$textboxValue2,'third'=>$textboxValue3,'fourth'=>
$textboxValue4,'fifth'=>$textboxValue5,'sixth'=>
$textboxValue6);
echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have textboxes, consider using [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of `.html`. `.val()` should be used for setting the value of form elements.

Also, the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method is deprecated, so please stop using it.

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: I have modified the code by removing the .live() method and using .val() instead of .html(). The textboxes still don't populate. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/UJf57E6J

Comment: @programm3r Seems fine. Is it `#mySelectBox` or `#verb` in the end? What do you get back from the server (what is in `data`)?

Comment: It should be #verb (the id of the selectbox). I edited the code above. Still nothing gets populated. How do you see what's in data? Can you see this in Firebug and, if so, where? Maybe there's a way to log what's in data to the console?

Comment: @programm3r Yes, the command for that is `console.log(data);`. You will see the contents in the console. You can also insert breakpoints and inspect the contents of local variables at that point of execution. Google for more information.

Comment: I tried putting console.log(data) right after the $.post line in the main index page and right before the data.first line, but it looks like the console.log(data) line and the textbox lines below it are never called. I also get the following error when trying to load the loadTextBox.php page "Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in line 16." Line 16 is while ($row = $result->fetch_object())

Comment: @programm3r So the problem is in your PHP. Seems like there are no results. Debug your PHP.

Comment: I have run my PHP through http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/phplint-on-line.html and the error message that pops up for line 16 is "Warning: `->' operator applied to a value of type unknown." Is there a quick fix for that and is that the same problem as the error "Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in line 16" from my comment above?

Comment: @programm3r There might be a problem with your SQL query (try to echo it to check), check for SQL errors, mysqli must have something for that. There can be a lot of things, I can't debug it for you because I don't have access to it. The error message says `$result` is not an object, so the query was not successful.

Comment: I already asked if PHP variables could be used in SQL queries and people on Stack Overflow said yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497606/php-variable-as-table-name-in-sql-query. Maybe there's something wrong with the line: $verb_value = $_POST['verb_value']; ?

Comment: $verb_value = $_POST['verb_value']; should be $verb_value = $_POST["verb_value"]; I'm still going to accept your answer though.

Comment: Since I have accepted the answer, I have removed the Pastebin link.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong jquery method to put values in textboxes

Replace this

```
$("#textbox").html(data.first);
```

With

```
$("#textbox").val(data.first);
```

Hope this will fix your problem.

Comment: I have modified the code by removing the .live() method and using .val() instead of .html(). The textboxes still don't populate. Here is my code: pastebin.com/UJf57E6J

Comment: Since I have accepted the answer, I have removed the Pastebin link.